# How to access files from a custom block without code

Tags: blocks

I've created a custom block in D8 via the UI. Is there any way to reference the files path in order to use images in the block without having to create a module?

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding, but in a custom block you should be able to use standard img tags to display an image you've uploaded to your site.

Comment: Yes, but the img tag needs the path to the image, and I'm looking for a way in D8 to not hardcode that path.